# node.js request post retrieve last id from db.json

Tags: node.js, request, json-server

After posting in db.json a new record (transaction with several data), I would like to get the id of the new record before going on. How-to do it ? I am stuck

I have in my db.json a "table" positions with an id automatically generated

my request is

```
request({
    url: url + '/api/positions,
    method: 'POST',
    form: transaction
}, ????);
```

I want in my callback retrieve position.id (as I have to use it in another part of code).

Thanks a lot

Olivier

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your API is giving back the position id, Im assuming you're using express, so in /api/positions have the response be res.send({position...});

EDIT, So you're asking about routing? Here is an awesome guide: https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html but Ill give you an example of what I mean.

```
app.post('/api/positions', function(req, res) { 
  //your logic goes here, so you are sending a 'transaction' object 
  // npm install and use body parser so you can retrieve attributes 
  // from the body of the post
  res.send({position: x}) 
})
```

Comment: could you just give me an example (it is one of my first dev with node.js, express and request)  as I just want to get the last record

Comment: Sorry I don't understand, I am lost

Comment: Maybe I am not clear and too junior !!! I have in my table "positions"     {
      "productCode": "FUT1",
      "id": 1
    },
    {
      "productCode": "FUT2",
      "id": 2
    },
When I post my transaction with request POST + FORM, I know that I will have     {
      "productCode": "FUT3",
      "id": 3
    },
in positions. I want to update my other object transaction with position.id = 3, I need this result in the callback function in order to amend transaction with transaction.positionId = 3

Comment: Can you show me your code? Yorur route code to be exact?

Comment: var request = require('request');
var util = require('util');
var port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
var url = 'http://127.0.0.1:' + port ;
var urlPositions = url + '/api/positions';
var urlTransactions = url + '/api/transactions';

Comment: Is that all the code? I mean the code where you set up the routing to make the POST/GET requests.

Comment: function Position_New(transaction, res) {

    function processResponse(error, res, body) {
        if (error) { throw new Error(error); 
        }
        else{}
}

    var posDate = new Date().toISOString().split('T')[0];

    util.log('Create a new position');
    transaction.posDate = posDate;

    request({
        url: urlPositions,
        method: 'POST',
        form: transaction
    }, 'mycallback');
}

Comment: HOw come you aren't using express? That's the only way you can get the server working. You don't even have a server running.

Comment: Even if I am not using Express, it seems that with request, I can update my db.json, but I must confess that I am learning by doing... I do not want to waste your time but it would be great if you could just draft me in one simple comprehensive example how to do?

Comment: https://expressjs.com/en/starter/hello-world.html in the url, go to port localhost:3000/ and youll see hello world.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe some thing like that.

```
...
var router = jsonServer.router('db.json');
...

// 'router.db.get' will fetch any first level attribute from your db.json
var positions = router.db.get('positions').value();
var lastPosition = positions[positions.length-1];
```